# php cannot work with a substring

Tags: php, mysql, insert, substring

I`m making a php file to generate users and inserting them in a database. The first thing I made is to obtain the latest one and save it in a variable, then, I use a function to obtain the integer part of the string and increment that value by one, but that is the part that I think is not working.

This is the code:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

function create_user($var){
    $prefix = "U";
    for($i = 0; $i < 5- strlen((String)$var); $i++) {
         $prefix .= '0';
    }
    $var = mb_substr($var, 1);

    if(is_numeric($var)) {
        $int = $var++;
        $var = $prefix . $int;
    }
    return $var;
}

$execute = mysqli_query($con, "select id_user from usuarios
    WHERE id_user=(SELECT MAX(id_user) FROM usuarios)");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
print_r($row['id_user']);
$var1 = $row['id_user'];

$userid=create_user($var1);

mysqli_query($con, "insert into usuarios (password, descripcion, id_user) 
    values ('A12345a', 'hgfhdgfh', ' $userid' )");

echo "hecho";
?>
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Why are you mix and matching mb_* and non-mb_* functions...?

Comment: Is the output of your `create_user()` function correct?

Comment: Please give an example of the string before it is passed to create_user() and after.

Comment: This is the string returned by the select U0001

Comment: Ok but what is passed INTO the function? An actual value In and out would be useful.

Comment: please give the data which you are giving as an input anf for that what you are getting output.

and try to work by making a bit change

mysqli_query($con, "insert into usuarios (password, descripcion, id_user) 
    values ('A12345a', 'hgfhdgfh', '". $userid."' )");

and see what output you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$int = $var++;
```

to:

```
$int = ++$var;
```

It's assigning the value of `$var` before incrementing.